# System.Threading.Thread.Sleep() freezes my code when clicking on a line

Tags: c#, console-application

I created a method for writing a text slowly for a game.
The problem is, when the method is running and I select something with mouse in cmd window, the whole program freezes and when I press escape it continues. Is there something I can do so it won't happen? Can I use something different than `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` for my program to wait?

```
static void slowly(string sen)
{
    for (int j=0; j<sen.Length-1; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(sen[j]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sen[sen.Length-1]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can make the thread *not* sleep. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov My whole program just freezes and doesn't come back.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov But I still want my program to wait, so what can I do, I'm sorry if I'm annoying I'm just new to this.

Comment: "click on a line in the cmd" as in "select something with mouse in cmd window"? - expected, all console output is blocked at that point (irrespective of Sleep)

Comment: you can use `Console.ReadLine` to make a console application wait till a user inputs something

Comment: @Jonesopolis I guess you didn't understand what I meant to do, I want to wait 0.1 seconds after writing each letter in a sentence so it seems like it's writing itself.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just want my program to wait a little bit after writing each letter -_-

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True enough.  Comment removed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, exactly what you meant, It just sounded like a rhetorical question.

Comment: @tomgrin10 I don't think you can do much to stop selection from blocking console output (`Esc` will cancel selection and let code continue). You may want to edit your question to clarify what happens. Also make sure to clarify that it is console app inline in the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edited my question but I don't really know what "console app inline" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your sleep code is running on the "Main Thread" of your application.  This means that your application can't really do anything else while it's in the .slowly() method.

You need to do something like what @vidstige shows, which is to have your .slowly() method run in another (helper) thread.

A more modern approach would be to:

```
        static async Task slowly(string sen)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sen.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(sen[j]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sen[sen.Length - 1]);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        });
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var slowlyTask = slowly("hello world");

        //do stuff while writing to the screen
        var i = 0;
        i++;

        //wait for text to finish writing before doing somethign else
        slowlyTask.Wait();

        //do another something after it's done;
        var newSlowlyTask = slowly("goodbye");
        newSlowlyTask.Wait();
    }
```

PS:  The amount of negative responses to this question is disappointing :(

Comment: +1 for "The amount of negative responses to this question is disappointing".  People could at least give a reason for their downvotes.

Comment: Note that this answer unlikely to help OP as the issue turned out to be with selection blocking all console output.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, thank you Alexei, I was about to write to write it myself. I can do fine with just a replacement for `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void slowly(string sen)
    {
        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
            for (int j=0; j<sen.Length-1; j++)
            {
                System.Console.Write(sen[j]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            System.Console.Write(sen[sen.Length-1]);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
```